# Port 22 is accepting connections, but not visible in netstat, unhide etc

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking

So I have this weird issue where one of my boxes is accepting connection on the ssh port (22) even after sshd is stopped. I tried to identify the listening process by the typical means

```
sudo netstat -antp | grep 22  # nothing
sudo unhide-tcp   # no hidden tcp ports
```

When I try to connect to port 22, it asks for a password even though I have setup key based authentication on this machine.

I'm afraid if there is a rootkit or some similar malware on my machine.

Have you seen something like this before?

OS - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: try from from root, without using sudo, for example sudo su - and after netstat -tunap | grep ssh

Comment: @c4f4t0r tried it now. nothing!

Comment: Does ssh -vvv reveal anything useful when connecting ? (target redirection, authentication methods tried, etc.. )?

Comment: Do you have checked your settings in inetd/xinetd?

Comment: @UwePlonus won't inetd/xinetd show up in netstat?

Comment: That's more than suspicious. If you got some rootkit in then you just can't trust **anything** you are using on this machine (common binaries, proc filesystem etc). That's time to grab your last backup for a fresh start.

Comment: @XavierLucas That's what I did. I ended up rebuilding the machine from a fresh image.

Answer (score 1):

If this is indeed a hidden process, and you are not making some sort of mistake (like inetd mentioned above by Uwe), try this:

- Bombard port 22 with a lot of bogus connections directly from ethernet
- See what pops up in top
- If nothing pops up, at least see if the load goes up significantly

For all of this to happen you must quench the rest of the traffic, so on a production server this can be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have setup key based authentication mechanism - it should be via a protocol such as ssh. but in your case can you pls try below:

Login to server and

> tail -f /var/log/secure

then from another terminal try to login and see what are the logs recorded there.

Check if SSH is configured to listen on another port as well -- in sshd_config file

Check iptables -- see if there is any port forwarding
check process

> sudo ps -ef |grep -i ssh

Check again with netstat all processes carefully

> netstat -tulpn